# ggplot2 time series plotting: how to omit periods when there is no data points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series with multiple days of data. In between each day there's one period with no data points. How can I omit these periods when plotting the time series using `ggplot2`?

An artificial example shown as below, how can I get rid of the two periods where there's no data?

code:

```
Time = Sys.time()+(seq(1,100)*60+c(rep(1,100)*3600*24, rep(2, 100)*3600*24, rep(3, 100)*3600*24))
Value = rnorm(length(Time))
g <- ggplot() 
g <- g + geom_line (aes(x=Time, y=Value))
g
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, create a grouping variable. Here, two groups are different if the time difference is larger than 1 minute:

```
Group <- c(0, cumsum(diff(Time) > 1))
```

Now three distinct panels could be created using `facet_grid` and the argument `scales = "free_x"`:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data.frame(Time, Value, Group)) + 
  geom_line (aes(x=Time, y=Value)) +
  facet_grid(~ Group, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely the best solution when you only have a few blocks.

Comment: Thx. I was trying to do this within one single plot but it seems that your method is still acceptable. Other packages like quantmod could do this perfectly right, but I guess this is not what ggplot2 is supposed to do.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that how does ggplot2 know you have missing values? I see two options:

1. Pad out your time series with `NA` values
2. Add an additional variable representing a "group". For example,

   ```
   dd = data.frame(Time, Value)
   ##type contains three distinct values
   dd$type = factor(cumsum(c(0, as.numeric(diff(dd$Time) - 1))))

   ##Plot, but use the group aesthetic
   ggplot(dd, aes(x=Time, y=Value)) +
         geom_line (aes(group=type))
   ```

   gives

   [image]

Comment: Thanks. But I would rather completely get rid of the blank periods in between (meaning even not shown in the x axis).

Comment: You didn't put that in your question ;) But the answer you accepted is  much nicer for only a few blocks and that's the one I would go for.

Answer (score 3):

csgillespie mentioned padding by NA, but a simpler method is to add one NA after each block:

```
Value[seq(1,length(Value)-1,by=100)]=NA
```

where the -1 avoids a warning.