# ggplot time series plotting: group by dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeserieschart

I would like to plot several time series on the same panel graph, instead of in separate panels.  I took the below R code from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136703/ggplot2-time-series-plotting-how-to-omit-periods-when-there-is-no-data-points/14136947#14136947).

Please note how the 3 time series are in 3 different panels. How would I be able to layer the 3 time series on 1 panal, and each line can differ in color.

```
Time = Sys.time()+(seq(1,100)*60+c(rep(1,100)*3600*24, rep(2, 100)*3600*24, rep(3, 100)*3600*24))
Value = rnorm(length(Time))
Group = c(0, cumsum(diff(Time) > 1))

library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data.frame(Time, Value, Group)) + 
 geom_line (aes(x=Time, y=Value, color=Group)) +
 facet_grid(~ Group, scales = "free_x")
```

If you run the above code, you get this:

[image]

When the `facet_grid()` part is eliminated, I get a graph that looks like this:

[image: ggplot bad graph]

Basically, I would like ggplot to ignore the differences in the dates, and only consider the times.  And then use `group` to identify the differing dates.

This problem could potentially be solved by creating a new column that only contains the times (eg. `22:01`, `format="%H:%M"`).  However, when `as.POSIXct()` function is used, I get a variable that contains both date and time. I can't seem to escape the date part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the data file has different days for each group's time, one way to get all the groups onto the same plot is to just create a new variable, giving all groups the same "dummy" date but using the actual times collected.

```
experiment <- data.frame(Time, Value, Group)  #creates a data frame
experiment$hms <- as.POSIXct(paste("2015-01-01", substr(experiment$Time, 12, 19)))  # pastes dummy date 2015-01-01 onto the HMS of Time
```

Now that you have the times with all the same date, you then can plot them easily.

```
experiment$Grouping <- as.factor(experiment$Group)  # gglot needed Group to be a factor, to give the lines color according to Group
ggplot(experiment, aes(x=hms, y=Value, color=Grouping)) + geom_line(size=2)
```

Below is the resulting image (you can change/modify the basic plot as you see fit):
[image]