# How can I ignore months while plotting timeseries?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with precipitation datewise.

```
head(df,n=5)
       Date        RCM
1 2018-01-01   31.38134
2 2018-01-02  273.23595
3 2018-01-03 1021.34547
4 2018-01-04  612.70087
5 2018-01-05   37.61821
```

my aim is to create timeseries for the winter season. I acheived so by extracting winter months from df and used ggplot.

```
    WIN1<-df[df$Date >= "2018-12-01" & df$Date <= "2018-12-31", ]    
    WIN2<-df[df$Date >= "2018-01-01" & df$Date <= "2018-02-28", ]    
    WIN<-rbind(WIN2,WIN1)
dfmelt<-melt(WIN,id.vars="Date")
ggplot(dfmelt,aes(x=Date,y=value,
                  col=variable))+
  labs(title='WINTER')+
  geom_line()
```

but this gives the plot with a flatine for the missing months. any way to transform this without the middle part to get a better looking plot.
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GDTS.png)

PS: any way of just plotting reverse x axes. so it dec to feb?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136703/ggplot2-time-series-plotting-how-to-omit-periods-when-there-is-no-data-points) solve your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 time series plotting: how to omit periods when there is no data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136703/ggplot2-time-series-plotting-how-to-omit-periods-when-there-is-no-data-points)

Comment: Not really. This is the final code I'm trying to run after many variations.

Comment: trying few variations but its not working. any way of simply plotting it with x axis having  Dec to Feb. so reverse and no other months?

Comment: to reverse datetime axis you need some hack. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626186/6912817) is a post . Note it uses functions of `scales` package so import it or modify the code e.g. as.trans should be scales::as.trans. Also change scale_x_continuous for scale_y_continuous